# What is the relationship between the absolute nature of the speed of light and the indeterminate nature of Heisenberg’s uncertainty principle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, speed-of-light, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, faster-than-light

What is the relationship between the absolute nature of the speed of light and the indeterminate nature of Heisenberg’s uncertainty principle?

Or to phase it differently, can any of a particle’s many superpositions involve faster than light travel?

To illustrate this point I will use a thought experiment. Imagine a tube exactly 1 light second long. An object moving at very close to the speed of light enters the tube. After 1 second the particle will not have left the tube as it is traveling less than the speed of light, so there’s a distance x remaining for it to travel in the tube. There is also some indeterminacy in its position y.

If the speed of the particle is increased until x is of the same size as y there should be a conflict between the consistency of the speed of light and the uncertainty principle. At some point very close to light speed the indeterminacy of position should breach the light barrier.

[This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/357247/calculate-the-uncertainty-in-velocity-of-electron) is similar but is not asking exactly the same thing. I suspect that the answer is yes some of a particle’s many superpositions can involve faster than light travel. But it would be useful to have this confirmed by someone who understands both quantum theory and relativity.

Comment: Note that the conjugate variable of position is *momentum*, not velocity. Does that shed any light on the matter? See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/357247/.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate the uncertainty in velocity of electron](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/357247/)

Comment: What is "the indeterminate nature of Heisenberg's uncertainty principle"?

Comment: No. I understand that momentum is involved but if there is a restriction on the uncertainty principle due to the speed of ligh this should still be detectable due to mass increase in excess of what would be expected if the speed of light was not a restriction.

Comment: Quantum mechanics by itself is non-relativistic. Using quantum mechanics only, you could indeed get such a result, but it would be wrong because you used a non-relativistic theory in a relativistic regime. My guess is that if you use relativistic quantum mechanics or quantum field theory to tackle this problem, the answer would be negative.

Comment: Sounds to me as if the answer is "we don't realy know". If so would an experiment be possible to determine which takes priority, would it be technicaly possible today and would it provide any insight into the boundry between relativity and quantum mechanics

Comment: @Bart Quantum mechanics is neither relativistic nor non-relativistic. The particular variations first developed and those taught in a first course are non-relativistic, but the framework of ideas can be either.

Comment: @WillO By "the indeterminate nature of Heisenberg's uncertainty principle" I meant its fuzziness for want of a better word. I was comparing the uncertain, indeterminate, statistical nature of quantum theory to the absolute, fixed consistency of the speed of light in relativity. Both are very accurate in their own spheres, but what happens in the corner cases? I’m trying to find a situation where quantum mechanics conflicts with relativity.

Comment: As mentioned in the proposed duplicate, a small position uncertainty causes a large *momentum* uncertainty. This does not in any way imply that the velocity becomes larger than the speed of light.

Comment: True. But the momentum uncertainty will tend towards a simple mass uncertainty at high velocity as the velocity component is trapped at the light barrier and can’t be “uncertain” across it. So the velocity component will be known with greater accuracy than you would normally expect due to the light barrier. If this is true then the uncertainty principle gives way to relativity. If some superpositions can be at greater than light speed then the reverse is true then relativity gives way to the uncertainty principle.